# Find the sum every two numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers and I'd like to find the sum of every two numbers in this array.

`Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6....]`

`Result = [3,7,11,...]`

Thank you

Comment: Try this - `for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i+=2) sum.push(array[i] + array[i+1]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let counter = 0;
let ret = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(counter === 0) {
    acc.push(curr);
    counter++;
  } else {
    acc[acc.length-1]+=curr;
    counter=0;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(ret);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

one more way to do tnat:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const odd = arr.filter((item, idx) => idx%2 - 1);
const even = arr.filter((item, idx) => idx%2);
const result = odd.map((val, idx) => val + (even[idx] || 0));

console.log(result);
```